# Unstable HDBSCAN & UMAP clustering results

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, dbscan

I've segmented my data using UMAP (dimensionality reduction, with a fixed random seed) and subsequently HDBSCAN to generate a number of clusters.
I've also looped through different values to fine-tune both UMAP and HDBSCAN to generate the optimal solution based on the relative_validity score embedded within HDBSCAN. I also split the data into train and test to ensure I wasn't overfitting.

My problem is that the solution seems to be a bit unstable - when I feed completely new data, UMAP and  HDBSCAN produce slightly different solutions. Whilst I understand there is an stochastic element to both algorithms, intuitively I would expect to always get roughly the same clustering structure.

Is this expected?
Does anyone know how to solve this?
Is there any step I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

````py
# UMAP
projection = umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=, n_components=, min_dist=, metric=, random_state=42)
train_projection = projection.fit_transform(train_data)

# Fit HDBSCAN
cluster = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=, min_samples=, gen_min_span_tree=True, prediction_data=True)
clusterer = cluster.fit(train_projection)
```
````

Comment: Some clarifications could help. Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "slightly different solutions"? By getting the sample clustering structure, do you mean the same number of clusters and relative number of points per cluster?

Comment: Hi @gianMa thanks for your question. At times I get different number of clusters using the same parameter specifications (so instead of getting 5 clusters as in the original solution, I get 4, or 6). So maybe a big cluster now gets split into two.

If I change the sample size, the parameter tuning also provides different results (because UMAP produces a different projection), so I also struggle to get similar results. My hypothesis is that, because both are density-focused solutions, a bigger sample size changes the density of points in the two-dimensional space...